# Excel - Finding all Values within a Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way for Excel to find all the values of one instance, such as "ABC" in a certain range and then return and sum the corresponding values.

I've been looking at VBA functions that do this, but is there a more simple way?

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding values"? Do you mean you have some values (like ABC, DEF, GHI) in column A for example, and want to sum what is in column B, but only for the rows where the value in column A is ABC?

Comment: Yes: 

ABC 1
DEF 3
ABC 3

And I would want the value 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RobertMS is correct, the SUMIF function will work:

```
ABC        | 1
DEF        | 1
ABC        | 3
Sum of ABC | =SUMIF(A1:A3,"ABC",B1:B3)
```

If you need a VBA function to find all the values in a range, then something like this will help:

```
Public Function FindAllInRange(Source As Range, Value As String) As Collection
    Dim Result As New Collection
    Dim CurCell As Range
    Dim ColIndex As Long
    Dim RowIndex As Long
    Dim Address As String

    ' Iterate through columns then rows
    For ColIndex = 1 To Source.Columns.Count
        For RowIndex = 1 To Source.Rows.Count
            Set CurCell = Source(RowIndex, ColIndex)
            ' Match the value (adjust this to your needs)
            If CurCell.Value = Value Then
                Address = CurCell.Worksheet.Name & "!" & CurCell.Address
                Debug.Print "Found match '" & Value & "' at: " & Address
                Result.Add CurCell, Address
            End If
        Next RowIndex
    Next ColIndex

    Set FindAllInRange = Result
End Function

Public Sub TestFindAllInRange()
    Dim Result As Collection
    Set Result = FindAllInRange(Selection, "ABC")
    Debug.Print "Found " & Result.Count & " cells"
End Sub
```

The SUMIF is far easier if it suits your needs. If you use a VBA function, then there is still work to do to sum the values. It is easy to get the count of the result collection, but you need to process the results to sum.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the SUMIF function? Sounds like that will do the trick for you.